# Combine equality operators with the inequality operator with firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform a query which is not working:

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> reference =
        firebaseFirestore.collection(path);
    reference = reference.where('userId', isNotEqualTo: userId);
    reference = reference.where('timestamp', isGreaterThan: lastReadTime);
```

Combining both of them is not working.

I have also tried:

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> reference =
        firebaseFirestore.collection(path);
    reference = reference.where('userId', isNotEqualTo: userId).where('timestamp', isGreaterThan: lastReadTime);

debugPrint("reference : ${reference.parameters}");
```

with same result.
The later parameter is not taken into as shown the following log.

```
reference : {where: [[FieldPath([userId]), !=, vxwe1qMIUkVa...]], orderBy: [], startAt: null, startAfter: null, endAt: null, endBefore: null, limit: null, limitToLast: null}
```

As you can see, `timestamp` is missing the printed parameters.
The result of the query is also not what I expected since the `timestamp` is ignored.

I have a composite index on `userId` and `timestamp`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Is there an error?  If so, please make that clear. Or are the query results different than you expect?  If the latter, what data are you querying, and what is your expected result?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: I have edited the post with more information

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically it is not possible as for now range and not equals comparisons must be done on the same field, as mentioned in the documentation.

```
In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.
```

[query opetators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators)